# expanding variables in awk

Tags: awk, variable

I have around 1000 files where on each of them if the first field matches a specific number , i need to print the corresponding 3rd element .
Since the number 7 below, is not constant and it based upon the output of previous script , when I am trying to pass a variable , it fails .

```
$cat ${i} | head -14 | awk '$1 == "7" {print $3}'
$Supervisor
$blah=7
$cat ${i} | head -14 | awk '$1 == "${blah}" {print $8}'
```

I have tried looking around with other combinations to escape/expand the variable inside the comparison , none of them seem to be able to expand the variable `blah`.

Comment: The shell variable is not being substituted because your awk scripts is inside single quotes.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is probably to pass it as an `awk` variable with `-v`

```
head -14 "$i" | awk -v blah="$blah" '$1 == blah {print $8}'
```

or without the `head` part:

```
awk -v blah="$blah" 'NR > 14 {exit} $1 == blah {print $8}' "$i"
```